# compare the choice of the user with the records in the database with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have 4 radio button and the user can choose a single choice of them, I want to check if this choice exists or not in the table question(this table contains the text of question, thei options, and the correcte answer) if it exists I want to increment the fields points Which is in the table test, and for do that the controller contains :

```
$userChoise = $request->answer;
$test = new Test;
$questions = DB::table('question')->get();

    foreach ($questions as $question) {
       if ($question->correcte == $userChoise) {

             $test->nbr_points = 10;
             $test->save();

         }else{

             $test->nbr_points = 0;
             $test->save();
            }
        }
```

**the problem** is that it does not take into consideration what is in the condition if it still runs the else processing

Comment: what is **$gtest**? and what fields is contain? and u put any relations?
you need to give us more details to give you exact answer

Comment: @MohamedSabil83 I do some modifications in the description, No there isn't relations between two tables

Comment: If you could please explain what is the condition, then we can do it with a single query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets revise your code a bit =)

```
$userChoise = $request->answer;
$test = new Test;
$correctAnswers = DB::table('question')->where('correcte', $userChoise)->count();

$test->nbr_points = $correctAnswers * 10;
$test->save();
```

Is that what you're looking for?